# Pass extra param sencha touch

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2, param, extra

I am new to Sencha touch. Please see my code below.

Model.js

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'memberlistModel',
        fields: [
            {  name :'memberId'},
            {  name: 'fullName' },
            {  name: 'phone' },
            {  name: 'age' },
            {  name: 'point' },
            {  name :'address'},
            {  name: 'emailAddress' },
            {  name: 'lastVisited'  },
            {  name: 'consumer_bbID'  },
            {  name: 'merchant_bbID'  },
            {  name: 'sessionId'  },
            {  name: 'deviceId'  },
            {  name: 'currentPoint'  },
        ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
//           url: 'http://192.168.251.131:8080/WebCommon/rest/BBWebService/getMembersList',

             url: 'http://mixsoloffice.no-ip.biz:82/WebCommon/rest/BBWebService/getMembersList',
//                  url: 'http://192.168.251.182:8080/WebCommon/rest/BBWebService/getMembersList',

            reader: 'json',
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'GET',
                update: 'PUT',
                destroy: 'DELETE'
            },

                      noCache: false, // get rid of the '_dc' url parameter

                    extraParams: {
                        sessionId: "1",
                        deviceId: "1",
                        merchant_bbID: "merchant1",

                    // add as many as you need
                },

//            timeout:1000,
//            listeners: {
//                exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
//                     alert("Connection Problem");
//                       Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false); // hide the load screen
//                       
//                  }
//               },

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'membersList'

            },

            writer: {
                type: 'json',

            },
        }

    }

});
```

Store.js

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   requires: [
              'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList'
    ],

    config: {
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (record) {
                return record.get('fullName')[0];
            }
        },


           model :'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList',
           storeId :'memberStore',
            autoLoad: true,
            clearOnPageLoad: false,  // This is true by default
            pageSize: 10,



    }
});
```

List.js

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'memberlistcard',
    requires: [
        'Ext.field.Select',
        'Ext.field.Search',

         'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
        'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',


    ],
    config: {

   styleHtmlContent: true,
        scrollable: 'vertical',

        singleSelect: true,

        grouped: true,
        variableHeights : false,
           store : { xclass : 'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList'},
            itemHeight :100,
        loadingText : 'loading',
        id :'memberlist',


            masked: {
                xtype: 'loadmask',
                message: 'loading...'
            }, // masked
       plugins: [

//                            { xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
//                                pullRefreshText: 'Pull down for more updates!',
//                                refreshFn:function(loaded, arguments){
//                                 
//                                    var store = Ext.getCmp('transactionlist').getStore();    
//                                    alert(store.getValue());


////                                    var transactionlist = Ext.getCmp('transactionlist');    
////                                   
////                                    transactionlist.setStore(store);





//                                }
//                             
//                    
//                            },

//                          { 
//                               xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
////                                 autoPaging: true,
//                              
//                                 
//                        
//                        },
                ],
        id :'memberlist',
        emptyText: '<p class="no-search-results">No member record found matching that search</p>',
        itemTpl: Ext.create(
            'Ext.XTemplate',
            '<div class="tweet-wrapper">',
                '<table>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td rowspan="2" width="28%" >',
//                        '<div style="padding-left: 30px;">',
//                        '   <img src="{imgUrl}" width="140" height="130" /></div>',
                        '</td>',
                        '<td>',
                        '   <div class="tweet">',
                        '       <h3>{consumer_bbID}</h3>',
                         '      <h3>Name: {fullName}</h3>',
                        '       <h3>Point Avalaible : {currentPoint} , Last Visited : {lastVisited}</h3>',

                        '   </div>',
                        '</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</table>',
            '</div>'


        ),



    },


});
```

I need to assign extra params value before the list render. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can take out Proxy from Model and set it to store in its initialize method. When you are creating the list create the store first and set the store in list specifically.

Check this out : [Dynamically define and load views with different proxy store in Sencha Touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633976/dynamically-define-and-load-views-with-different-proxy-store-in-sencha-touch-2/15651558#15651558) to see how to set custom proxy in store during initialization.